# Sorting a column based on the value of another

Tags: awk

I have a file with the following structure:

Input

```
1   30923   2   300 G:0.503333  T:0.496667  T
1   51476   2   300 T:0.986667  C:0.0133333 C
1   51479   2   300 T:0.966667  A:0.0333333 T
```

What I would like to do is to change the position of the fifth and sixth column in a way that one column gets the order identical as of the seventh column. You can see in the example. In the seventh column, we have T, C, T and after the change, the sixth column from T, C, A has changed into T, C, T in the output, that is in the third line, the position of the fifth and sixth columns have switched when compared to the seventh column.

Output

```
1   30923   2   300 G:0.503333  T:0.496667  T
1   51476   2   300 T:0.986667  C:0.0133333 C
1   51479   2   300 A:0.0333333 T:0.966667  T
```

I hope I could explain clearly, I have not been able to find a solution, could you please give me a hint as how to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So do you always want the 6th column to follow the order of 7th column?

Comment: Basically, what I want is to reorder one of the 5th or 6th column to have exactly the same order of letters as the 7th of column, it doesn't matter whether that is the 5th or the 6th. Thanks.

Comment: How do you expect to decide which of the columns to re-order? And are you always just going to be swapping the value with the other column to make this happen?

Comment: also what happens when none of the two columns match the last column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using output as tab delimiters and all columns justified.

```
awk -F'[ :]*'  '{if($7 == $9 ) print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9; else print $1,$2,$3,$4,$7,$8,$5,$6,$9}' input.txt|column -t
```

Output:

```
1  30923  2  300  G  0.503333   T  0.496667   T
1  51476  2  300  T  0.986667   C  0.0133333  C
1  51479  2  300  A  0.0333333  T  0.966667   T
```

Comment: This works great. Just one question, how can I make the output homogenous, that is all lines get printed like the third one, the way you have removed the ":". I would also print columns in a tab separated format. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, maybe this will work for you?

: file a.awk

```
substr($6,1,1) == $7 { print }
substr($6,1,1) != $7 { print $1, $2, $3, $4, $6, $5, $7 }
```

: file a.txt

```
1   30923   2   300 G:0.503333  T:0.496667  T
1   51476   2   300 T:0.986667  C:0.0133333 C
1   51479   2   300 T:0.966667  A:0.0333333 T
```

bash-3.2$ awk -f a.awk a.txt

```
1   30923   2   300 G:0.503333  T:0.496667  T
1   51476   2   300 T:0.986667  C:0.0133333 C
1   51479   2   300 A:0.0333333 T:0.966667  T
```